# Extract words (date) from free text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract the date part (so the May 2020) from this column and put in the form mm/yyyy in a new column for another table. But because this column can be free text, it can look different.

1.The last date was when I was 5 years old in May 2020.

2.In 05/1999, I was there.

Expected result for my new field:

05/2020

05/1999

I honestly just want to be able to cover ground as much as I can, I'm not sure how to extract the year from the text which is the biggest problem though because sometimes there can be numbers before and after the year like in 1.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio for this BTW.

Comment: *SQL Server Management Studio* is just a client application to SQL Server; what is your SQL server version? `select @@version`

Comment: [You just posted this and deleted it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73180767/14868997) Please don't repost the exact same question, edit your original to improve it so it can be reopened

Comment: The issue with your original question remains: There is no way for the server to "guess" what is meant. The best you can do is look for two or four digit numbers using `SUBSTRING(YourValue, NULLFI(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', YourValue), 0), 4)` for example

Comment: This will be awkward and subject to numerous edge cases, there's simply not enough info here for anyone to offer a viable solution, I would perhaps look at using a string_split solution combined with joining to a known list of month names that could appear where you can append the following row which might be a year and try_cast to a valid date from which to select date parts; or similarly look for 4-digit numbers and append the preivous row that might be a month etc...

Comment: @Charlieface I edited the original question because it was too universal and listed a lot more cases originally than now so Im sorry if this is still too much. My approach was to make different case expressions for it, so with your substring suggestion, I think that returns the year or month which is good, but how do I actually check if there is a year in the text (or month)?

Comment: What I gave you would return `NULL` if there is no 4-digit number in the value... `NULLIF` not `NULLFI` sorry

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working but silly solution building upon Stu's idea. The question is not really answerable in any guaranteed way anyway, so this was just an exercise for fun.

I build a table of months that I will recognise, and a utility table of integers up to 1024.

In the `cleansed` CTE I use a strip out any characters that aren't either letters, numbers or a space character by checking each character individually with the help of the `ints` CTE, and then put the clean letters back together with `string_agg`.

Since I know there are no longer any symbols in the string, this allows me to tag the start of each word with my own identifiable symbol, a leading minus sign. This prevents partial word matches with `charindex` in the next step.

In the `words` CTE, I break the string into words using `string_split`, using `charindex` to get the word position. Since `charindex` will get the first whole word match, and there might be more than one whole word match, I reverse both terms. The presumption here is that we prefer a "month like" component that appears prior to a "year-like" component.

Finally, I look for a ("month-like", "year-like") pair, prioritising pairs where the month appears before the year, and then on the smallest separation between month and year.

Honestly, the biggest gap in the logic comes from the fact that `string_split` doesn't return any position information, which is dumb, forcing a reliance on `charindex`, which is not reliable in the case of duplicate words. (`string_split` may apparently be fixed in SQL Server 2022, in the meantime you can roll your own split and get rid of the `charindex` logic for word order).

I do *not* recommend running this against a large number of sentences.

```sql
create table #sentences
(
   sentence varchar(1024)
);

delete from #sentences;

insert #sentences values
('The last date was when I was 5 years old in May 2020'),
('In 05/1999, I was there.'),
('expect no result, no month here 2022'),
('expect no result, no year here may'),
('expect no result, no year here 05'),
('expect no result, 123456789'),
('expect no result, 01 02 03 04'),
('expect feb2022 result, leading month prioritised over trailing month, 02 2022 01'),
('expect jun2022 result, 6 5 6 2022'),
('expect aug2022 result, in August 2022 I ate 2000 jelly beans'),
('expect aug2022 result, in August 2022 I may have eaten 2000 jelly beans');


with months as 
(
   select   *
   from     (
               values (1,  '-Jan', '-January'),
                      (2,  '-Feb', '-February'),
                      (3,  '-Mar', '-March'),
                      (4,  '-Apr', '-April'),
                      (5,  '-May', '-May'),
                      (6,  '-Jun', '-June'),
                      (7,  '-Jul', '-July'),
                      (8,  '-Aug', '-August'),
                      (9,  '-Sep', '-September'),
                      (10, '-Oct', '-October'),
                      (11, '-Nov', '-November'),
                      (12, '-Dec', '-December')
            ) t (monthNum, shortName, longName)
),

ints as
(
   select top 1024 rn = row_number() over (order by message_id) from sys.messages
),

cleansed as
(
   select      sentence =  '-' 
                           + replace
                           (
                              string_agg(t.c, '') within group (order by i.rn),
                              ' ', 
                              ' -'
                           )
   from        ints        i
   cross apply (
                  select      sentence,
                              c = iif(t.c like '[0-9a-Z ]', t.c, ' ')
                  from        #sentences 
                  cross apply ( values (substring(sentence, i.rn, 1))) t(c)
                  where       i.rn <= len(sentence)
                              and sentence like '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
               ) t   
   group by    sentence
),

words as
(
   select      sentence, 
               t.word, 
               pos = row_number() over (partition by sentence order by u.pos desc)
   from        cleansed
   cross apply (select * from string_split(sentence, ' ')) t(word)   
   cross apply (select charindex(reverse(t.word), reverse(sentence))) u(pos)
),
priortisedMatches as
(
   select      [priority]     =  row_number() over (partition by w.sentence order by t.separation asc),
               [MM/yyyy]      =  concat
                                 (
                                    format(t.monthNum, '00/'), 
                                    replace(w.word, '-', '')
                                 ),
               cleanSentence  =  replace(w.sentence, '-', '')
   from        words w
   cross apply (
                  select   top 1 
                           m.monthNum,
                           separation = abs(w1.pos - w.pos)
                  from     words  w1
                  join     months m on w1.word in (m.shortName, m.longName) 
                                       or -try_cast(word as int) = m.monthNum
                  where    w1.sentence = w.sentence
                  order by sign(w1.pos - w.pos) asc,
                           abs(w1.pos - w.pos) asc
               ) t 
   where       w.word like '-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
)

select [MM/yyyy], cleanSentence
from   priortisedMatches
where  [priority] = 1;

/* produces:

08/2022     expect aug2022 result  in August 2022 I ate 2000 jelly beans
08/2022     expect aug2022 result  in August 2022 I may have eaten 2000 jelly beans
02/2022     expect feb2022 result  leading month prioritised over trailing month  02 2022 01
06/2022     expect jun2022 result  6 5 6 2022
05/1999     In 05 1999  I was there 
05/2020     The last date was when I was 5 years old in May 2020
*/
```